# Remove Chart Hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

How do I remove a chart hyperlink?

I have tried the following code, but it does not seem to have removed the link.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
ActiveChart.Hyperlinks.Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim c As Chart
'Set c = ActiveChart ' or...
Set c = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart

'add hyperlink 
c.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1), Address:="", _
    SubAddress:= "'Product'!A1"

'now remove hyperlink
With c.Hyperlinks
    For i = .Count To 1 Step -1
        .Item(i).Delete
    Next i
End With
```

As you see, I'm deleting the hyperlinks one by one, counting backwards from the last to the first.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-Francois Corbett, although this doesn't seem to work either. I should perhaps point out (if it makes a difference) that the hyperlink was created using the following code: ActiveChart.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1), Address:="", SubAddress:= "'Product'!A1". Using your code, I am met with a 91 run-time error in the C.Hyperlinks line of code.

Comment: You made me look up what error 91 is... I don't know them all by heart, you know! (sigh) Ok, searched it; it's "Object variable or With block variable not set." That means `c` is `Nothing`, which again probably means that no chart is active. Ok, did you activate a chart? Did you try reusing the code you already wrote to do so? Edited my answer to illustrate this.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-Francois Corbett - that's the error solved, and the macro now runs smoothly. However it still does not remove the hyperlink. It would appear that the hyperlink is somehow not a typical one! Could the code I used to create the hyperlink (noted in the first comment) shed some light on this?